# sql query to check if 2 events overlaps

Tags: mysql, sql, date, overlap

My table has 3 columns name, start_date and end_date 
I need to insert a record in a table only if the date of the new event don't overlap an existing event.
So, say I have an event with start date 1/1/2015 and end date 31/12/2015
I can't insert an event if has dates like these:

- 31/12/2014 - 1/1/2016
- 2/1/2015 - 30/12/2015
- 31/12/2014 - 1/6/2015
- 2/1/2015 - 1/1/2016

Or, talking about integrers:

- Existing record with range 2...6

Possible invalid records:

- 1..3
- 3..5
- 5..7
- 1..7

What's the shorter expression to match this condition?

Comment: What rdbms are you working with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any 2 ranges overlap if (and only if) the first start is smaller then the second end, while the second start is smaller then the first end.

Therefor, you want to test your incoming record has a start date and end date that does not match this condition for any record in the table.

Here is a visual proof - all of the ways two lines can overlap:

```
1.
s1|--------|e1
s2|--------|e2


2.
s1|-------|e1
     s2|--------|e2


3.
     s1|--------|e1
s2|--------|e2


4.
s1|-------------------|e1
     s2|--------|e2


5.
     s1|--------|e1
s2|-------------------|e2
```

As you can see, `s1` is always smaller then `e2`, while `s2` is always smaller then `e1`.

This is not the case when the two lines does not overlap:

```
1.
s1|--------|e1
                 s2|--------|e2


2.
                 s1|--------|e1
s2|--------|e2
```

As you can see here, either `s1` is bigger then `e2` or `s2` is bigger then `e1`.

The actuall data type is completely irrelevant as long as it's comparable.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this condition is enough, see my update in the Question description

Comment: Data type is irrelevant as long as it's comparable.

Comment: Nice answer, would be nice to have pseudoCode!

Comment: @Tobia I have almost no experience with MySql. I can easily write an SQL Server code example but I don't think that would help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tablename 
WHERE :inputDate1 BETWEEN date1 AND date2 
OR :inputDate2 BETWEEN date1 AND date
OR date1 >= :inputDate1
OR date2 <= :inputDate2
```